# Clipping through floor on Emerald Coast

Tags: sonic-generations-3ds

I have a problem on the "Emerald Coast" stage in Sonic Generations on the 3DS.  On one hill I seem to just clip through. This is fine with modern Sonic, but only occurs with classic Sonic, thus not letting me progress in the game.

What I want to know is this a game-breaking bug or just a glitch? I payed 20 pounds for this and I might return it.

Comment: Based on this video https://youtu.be/0sYrn9vrm8k?t=1633 As what point does the glitch happen? (The video should start @ 16minutes33seconds, with classic sonic running Emerald Cost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick look online, I found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL7TALx1S60), which I think might be what is happening with your game.

[A bit of research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_Generations#Reception) tells me that Sonic Generations on the 3DS did not receive as good reviews as it did on other consoles, but it still was not picked up for being unplayable.

That said, if you are experiencing bugs (especially if it is making the game unplayable), **[UK consumer law should entitle you to a full refund or exchange](http://www.thetechgame.com/News/sid=1263/purchased-a-buggy-game-youre-allowed-a-refund-in-the-uk.html)**.

Comment: I'm making an assumption, given that OP payed "20 pounds", which I'm only aware of being used in the UK. Just to clarify, I do not live in the UK. I'm basing my answer of the articles I found, not my personal experience.

Comment: @Mrfunny744, if you want to clarify either way, your rights are different in different countries. It is still pretty easy to find the right information so I can easily change my answer for your particular circumstance.

Comment: Just to let you know, I do live in the uk

Comment: Thank you very much. Game has a 28 day return policy so i'll return it today.

Comment: @Mrfunny744 - remember to mark this answer as your accepted answer if it helps you :). You can do this by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. :)

Comment: Hold on @Timelord64 While that Video is from Sonic Gen, it's from the Console/PC port and not the 3DS version.  There's issues on both versions of the game, but nothing game breaking where the user cannot restart the game. (On the other hand, it is possible to get stuck sometimes if you're going too fast or manage to escape the bounds of a level.)

Comment: Very observant, @NBN-Alex. I still believe this is what is happening to OP, whether a different version, or a different game entirely.